# Discord.js ReferenceError: message is not defined

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, discord.js

I am trying to make a command to clear messages in my discord and I receive the error message is not defined. Above the error inside of the terminal there is one specific portion under my `return` for the first line with it, there is an arrow pointing up to it.

Here is my code for the main portion

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
 
const prefix = '!';
 
const fs = require('fs');
 
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
 
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
 
 
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Codelyon is online!');
});
 
client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
 
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
 
    if(command == 'ping') {
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } 
    else if(command == 'ouryoutube') {
            client.commands.get('youtube').execute(message, args);
    } 
    else if(command == 'clear') {
            client.commands.get('clear').execute(message, args);
    }
});
```

Here is my code for the command

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'clear',
    description: "Clear Messages",
    execute(messages, args) {
        if(!args[0]) return message.reply("You must enter the number of messages you want to clear");
        if(isNaN(args[0])) return message.reply("Please Enter a Real Number.");
        
        if(args[0] > 100) return message.reply("You can't delete more then 100 messages");
        if(args[0] < 1) return message.reply("You must delete at least one message");
    }
}
```

Thank you any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in `execute(messages, args) {...}`. The first argument should be `message`.

```js
execute(message, args) {
  // code
}
```